# Which constructor will be called at the time of page load in below scenario

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have written controller like below with some overloaded constructors -

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    public TestController() { }

    public TestController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
    {    
        pageInit();
    }

    public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {     
        pageInit();
    }    
}
```

Page code is something like this -

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"
        recordSetVar="Opportunity" title="Select Opportunity"
        extensions="TestController" wizard="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"
        tabStyle="Opportunity" readOnly="false" cache="false">

</apex:page>
```

1) How to identify which constructor will be called at the time of page load when overloaded constructors are there?

2) In the above scenario is there any way to call default constructor at the time of page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Which constructor will be called for an extension?

The constructor for an extension used in the Apex is determined by the VisualForce page, based on the `recordsetVar` attribute.

If `recordsetVar` is defined in the apex:page element, the platform will try to inject an `ApexPages.StandardSetController` and will fail if there is no constructor that takes one as parameter.

If `recordsetVar` is not set, the platform will try to inject an `ApexPages.StandardController`.

### Can the default constructor be called?

Yes, by defining your VF page to load the class as a controller, not an extension. If the page is defined with `standardController="Opportunity" extensions="MyClass"` then MyClass will be instantiated as a controller extension, with a standard controller or standard set controller injected into it, as above. 
If the page is defined as `controller="MyClass"` then MyClass will be instantiated as controller in its own right, with nothing injected, using the default constructor.

Comment: Thank you @Dominic for such a detailed explanation.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

In the page you used a `extensions="TestController"` and `recordSetVar="Opportunity`

```
 public TestController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
```

will be invoked because `recordSetVar` defines that `Standard Set constructor` should be invoked

Default constructor will be called for case when you will use a class as a `controller` on VF page or you can invoke default constructor via `this()` statement

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    public TestController() { 
        System.debug('default constructor');
    }

    public TestController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {   
       this(); 
       System.debug('standard set constructor');
       
    }

    public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {    
        this();  
        System.debug('extension constructor');
    }   
    
}
```

The result will be:

> 11:17:43.042 (42222183)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|default constructor
>
> 11:17:43.042 (42268784)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|standard set constructor

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you use this page.

If you go to yourPage?id=1518characterss then the standard will be called.

If you go to yourPage?rlid=1518characterss&id=1518characterss then the standardSet constructor will be called.

1) Ues JS to parse the URL.

2) Is there any chance that you want to use action attribute of [page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) tag?